# Using EventBrite oAuth from a windows phone app

Tags: windows, mobile, oauth, eventbrite

I am trying to use oAuth with Event Brite via a windows phone application.  Is there a mobile version of the login page that would be more friendly on a windows mobile device?

Comment: +1 The same problem for Windows 8, even for Desktop one. To support oAuth you are almost required to use Windows 8 Authentication Broker that provides too narrow iframe for that purpose. Have you found any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently not a mobile-optimized Eventbrite login page.